# UIButton with different actions

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift2

I want to have **1** button with different actions. When I tap the first time the button, only the button name should be changed. When I tap again I want to show the first ViewController.

My problem is that when I tap the first time it is immediately showing the first ViewController. Can you help me please?

Thanks

```
@IBAction func startPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: ViewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView") as! ViewController1

    var m: Bool?
    m = true
    if (m == true) {
        startPressed2.setTitle("Try Again", forState: .Normal)
        m = false
    }
    if (m == false) {
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *lot* of problems with that code.

One problem is that `m` is a purely local variable, so it is created and set to `true`, freshly, every time `startPressed` is called.

Instead, promote it to be an instance property by declaring it *outside* of any method. Now it will persist, so you can check it again the next time `startPressed` is called.

Also, your Optional here is silly; don't use Optionals without a reason. Plus, you can define and initialize all in one move, and you don't need an explicit type.

So:

```
var m = true
@IBAction func startPressed(sender: UIButton) {
```

Also, never compare a Bool to `true` or `false`; the Bool *is* the condition. And you don't need parentheses.

Finally, if all you want to do when `m` is true is set the title, then you need to *stop*. You can do that with `return`, or by using `else`:

```
if m {
    startPressed2.setTitle("Try Again", forState: .Normal)
    m = false
} else {
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: And if you don't understand about the scope and lifetime of different kinds of variable, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: I changed that now, but my problem is that when the button name is changing it shows the View Controller at the same time. I don't want it at the same time

Comment: Thank you a lot, this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because when you play your code, `m = false` statement is executed in  the first if, after that the second if condition is correct `if (m == false)` so it plays the code below.

Try this:

```
var m:Bool = true

@IBAction func startPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: ViewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView") as! ViewController1

    if (m == true) {
        startPressed2.setTitle("Try Again", forState: .Normal)
        m = false
    }else{
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```